# LEFT JOIN with 3 TABLES query brings multiple times the same row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With this query

```
select 
    google_ads.date,
    oh_db.customer_name,
    linkedin.cost as linkedin_cost,
    google_ads.cost as google_ads_cost
from `oh-data-pipeline`.`staging_benjamin`.`oh_customers` as oh_db

left join `oh-data-pipeline`.`staging_benjamin`.`linkedin` as linkedin
    on oh_db.linkedin_account_id = linkedin.account_id

left join `oh-data-pipeline`.`staging_benjamin`.`google_ads` as google_ads
    on oh_db.google_ads_id = google_ads.customer_id

order by google_ads.date desc
```

I get the following result which is not possible because I should have only 1 unique record and not 76 times the same.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

I am querying from this database : 1 row per customer per day
[image]

and that database : 1 row per customer per day.
[image]

NB :Distinct does not i don't get the right "cost" value.

Comment: If you look carefully, you find entire row is not duplicate. Especially last one. However, FOR first two rows  you can use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: It's not because the join is an outer join. It's just a feature of joins. That's how they work.

Comment: Thanks ! I have edited the question i will be much clearer. I am querying from only two tables that have each for 1 specific date 1 account ID and 1 cost. Any Clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fanning out by doing the `JOIN` only on `account_id`. 
Every row for every `account_id` is joining with all of the same for each date and each table.

Try adding an `AND table_1.date = table_2.date` on the `ON ...` clauses.

If it doesn't work, I can help you rewrite your query later.

To learn a little more about the un-intentional [fanning out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fan%20out) of your results, due to the way you joining your tables, check this [explanation](https://looker.com/blog/aggregate-functions-gone-bad-and-the-joins-who-made-them-that-way) by Looker.

Comment: thanks ! I am new to sql and did not now I could perform AND on a join... THANK YOU SOOO MUCH. I was SOOOO Stuck !